# Atlassian Bamboo - Display JMeter test results using JMeter Aggregator plugin

Tags: bash, jmeter, bamboo, jmeter-plugins

I've been tasked to install and figure out how to use the JMeter Aggregator plugin for Bamboo on a locally built vagrant server with Bamboo on it on my machine so I can learn how to use it before putting it on the project that I'm working on's Bamboo instance but I can't figure out how to get the Aggregator plugin to actually read any of the test results properly so it keeps failing the assertions.

Currently, I've just set up a JMeter test through the gui client and saved the .jmx to my jmeter folder on the vagrant server so I can run it headless from a bash script and send the results to a .jtl file in another directory.  Below is the bash script:
[image: The bash script to run the jmeter test and log the results into the .jtl file]

I've got the Aggregator plugin installed and I've pointed it to the resulting .jtl file but when I try and put any assertions on it, it breaks the build and says the assertion failed because the value was 0, which is not actually the case.  Below is the current configuration I've got on the plugin - I've tried changing the filepath to an absolute one but that didn't fix it so I don't know if it's pointed at the wrong file or if it needs to be XML to do anything with the data it gets out?
[image: The plugin's setup]

If anyone could offer any guidance on this, I'd really appreciate the assist - been struggling with this for a couple of days now and there's precious little in the way of documentation on it...

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old post, I recently came across a similar issue.
hope this helps.
Bamboo looks for .jtl files in working directory of the job. So instead changing directory give absolute/relative path of the JMeter executable file changing the command to

> `bash <path to jmeter executable>jmeter -n -t <path to jmx>/steve.jmx -l results.jtl`

While giving Build log file path use expression like

> `**/<file_name>.jtl` (for picking up specific file)

or you can also use

> `**/*.jtl` (to pickup all files available in working dir).